# Unit testing presence of mat-error after touching and untouching mat-input

Tags: html, angular, typescript, unit-testing, dom

How would I test that the mat-error is present in the DOM when I haven't touched the input, and also when I have touched and untouched the input without entering any text?

I am testing using Jest

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput formControlName="someInput"/>
  <mat-error id="my_error">* required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Test**

```
it('Should not show error', () => {
  const myEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#my_error'));

  expect(myEl).toBeUndefined();
});

it('Should show error', () => {
  const myEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#my_error'));

 // code to touch and untouch the element

  expect(myEl).not.toBeUndefined();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("[formControlName='someInput']"));
const errors = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css("mat-error"));

input.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
fixture.detectChanges();

expect(errors.length).toEqual(1);
expect(errors[0].nativeElement.innerHTML.trim()).toMatch("* required");
```